# Geometry Nodes: Create Triangles out of random Points on Mesh

Tags: geometry-nodes, shader-nodes

I want to remesh my object by creating points on my surfaces, realizing them as vertices, and connecting them via edges in the form of polygons, but I don't know how.

The idea is to get a mesh of triangles or larger polygons of any size. I think the closest points should be considered. The best case would be that this only applies to the outer faces. I want these edges to be created because the next step will be tessellation along these edges to bring these triangles into three dimensional formations. This is an experimental approach to design and I am writing my bachelor's degree with this. I hope I could clarify some questions.

I can imagine that this question is very specific and can not be realized, but I am also very grateful for other advice for workarounds or fakes. Like for example a shader. That's why I added shader to the tags.

[image: My Mesh so far with the points distributed on the surface]
[image: My Nodesetup so far]

Comment: What you have in mind will not work with *Geometry Nodes* in this way. There are simply too many variables here. At which points should edges be created here? Which point should have a connection with which point? ...I ask myself first and foremost: What is the point of all this? Why do you want to create such a mesh at all? What is its purpose? ...because the result will not be particularly useful or beautiful, so there must be a certain reason for it. Please tell us more about it.

Comment: If edited the question. Hopfully its more clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't Know if it will do the trick.
By subdividing a lot then use a `Merge by Distance`, playing on the distance you will obtain a mesh similar to what you expect? Then add the points by instancing them on this mesh...

[image]

I am very not sure on this one.

**Edit:**In order to affect only the verticals faces it's possible to use the normal like this:

[image]

The New .blend that affect only vertical faces...

[image]

Comment: That looks realy good ill try this thank you. Is ther a way to only apply this to the vertical faces?

Comment: Of course it's possible i upload a new .blend...